# download word document in same window?

Tags: visualforce

I am using custom button in standard view page for generating word document. When i click on button, a new window is opening and document generated in that window. I don't want new window. How can i download the document in same window.

[image]

Comment: share the button script here

Comment: I am assinging VF page for the button. If i change behavior "Display in existing window" standard view page redirecting to VF word document page and document downloaded. But i want stay standard page only.

Comment: @Ratan, some what it's working. onclick will not opening new window but it's  opening new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an Extension to your Visual force page with the below code:

```
contentType="application/msWord#yourFile.doc"
```

So, your word will be downloaded without displaying  a new window.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i am using that one. but not getting.

Comment: Strange. Any errors? Have you checked any wrong typos in contentType?

Comment: No errors, it's redirecting standard page to vf page in same tab. but i want to stay in standard view page. My tag is like contentType="application/msWord#HR_WordDocument.doc"

Comment: I hope you're developing the VF page in respective instance only. In that case, it will redirected and remain in same VF page. Please disable the Development Mode and test the button. You will get your expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, now i got. Disabled the development mode. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers. If you've free time please mark reply as an answer and give rating. Thanks.